# Sum Two Generated Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table like

```
+------------------+-----+
| ID TIPE A TIPE B  |    |
+------------------+-----+
| 1    52    4      |    |
| 2    41    7      |    |
| 3    30    4      |    |
+------------------+-----+
```

where the `TIPE A` and `TIPE B` are generated columns. I'd like to create a column `TIPE C` that will be the sum of `TIPE A` and `TIPE B`.

```
+--------------------------+----+
| ID TIPE A TIPE B  TIPE C |    |
+--------------------------+-----+
| 1    52    4       56    |    |
| 2    41    7       48    |    |
| 3    30    4       34    |    |
+--------------------------+----+
```

My `SELECT` is something like

```
SELECT
c.id AS 'ID',
SUM(CASE
    WHEN code = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) 'TIPE A',
SUM(CASE
    WHEN mt.tipe LIKE '%tipe_b%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS 'TIPE B'
FROM 
[...]
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What do YOU mean by "generated columns"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do simple way

```
SELECT *, (TIPE A + TIPE B) as TIPE C FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways for you to do this:

By using subqueries

```
select 'ID', 
       'TIPE A', 
       'TIPE B', 
       'TIPE A' + 'TIPE B' as 'TIPE C'
  from ([your actual select statement])
```

or create a new column with the combined logic for 'TIPE A' and 'TIPE B'

```
...
SUM(CASE
    WHEN code = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END + 
CASE
    WHEN mt.tipe LIKE '%tipe_b%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) 'TIPE C'
...
```

Depending on the complexity of your query one way or another can fit best.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can significantly simplify the expressions.  But you do need to repeat them:

```
SELECT c.id AS ID, SUM(code = 0) as tipe_a, SUM(mt.tipe LIKE '%tipe_b%') as tipe_b,
        SUM( (code = 0) OR mt.tipe LIKE '%tipe_b%')) as tipe_a_or_b,
        SUM(code = 0) + SUM(mt.tipe LIKE '%tipe_b%') as sum_either
FROM t;
```

You seem to specify `sum_either`, but I think you might want `tipe_a_or_b`.